# Differences between HttpMessageHandler and HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

HttpHandler was a standard method of intercepting and modifying the processing of an http request in ASP.NET.

HttpMessageHandler is the underlying type for the DelegatingHandler, which is the standard method of intercepting and modifying the processing of an http request in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI.

But you can still use HttpHandlers in ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI.

So what is there difference between these two?  Assuming a pipeline containing one of each, when does HttpHandler.ProcessRequest fire in the pipeline as compared to HttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (i.e. which fires first)?

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: I have but my experiments have not been sufficiently illuminating to date.

Answer (score 0):

This is just two different things. Web Api introduces another alternative to intercept http messages. You can use them both if you will.

As for the sequence:
It looks like:
[image]

If you are interested in more details regarding ApiControllers/AuthorizeAttributes and DelegatingHandlers you can read my post:
http://dotrelusion.blogspot.de/2014/05/web-api-claims-authorization.html